# Trie Data Structure Insertion and Compression implementation in Java using Concurrent Hash Map

Tags: java, hashmap, trie, concurrenthashmap

Trying to implement Trie data structure addition of elements and then trying to to reduce it as trie compression mechanism. There is a specific use case due to which the implementation is running forever as an infinite loop, may we have a look at it and see what could be the best possible base condition for that.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class TrieNode {

    private String value;
    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, TrieNode> children;
    private boolean isWord;

    public TrieNode(String value){
        this.value = value;
        this.children = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, TrieNode>();
    }

    public static void sortbykey(ConcurrentHashMap<String, TrieNode> map) {
        ArrayList<String> sortedKeys = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());

        Collections.sort(sortedKeys);

    }

    public static ArrayList<TrieNode> hashMapValues (ConcurrentHashMap<String, TrieNode> map) {
        ArrayList<TrieNode> nodeList = new ArrayList<TrieNode>(map.values());
        return nodeList;
    }

    public ArrayList<TrieNode> getChildren() {
        sortbykey(this.children);
        return hashMapValues(this.children);
    }

    public ConcurrentHashMap<String, TrieNode> getChildrenMappings()
    {
        return this.children;
    }

    public void addChild(int numCharacters,String value)
    {
        //If we have arrived at the root level
        if(value.length() == numCharacters)
        {
            this.isWord = true;
        }
        //If the value still has more characters then add a child
        else
        {
            TrieNode nextNode = null;
            String nextCharacter = Character.toString(value.charAt(numCharacters));
            if(this.children.get(nextCharacter)==null)
            {
                String nextPrefix = value.substring(0,numCharacters+1);
                nextNode = new TrieNode(nextPrefix);
                this.children.put(nextCharacter, nextNode);
            }
            numCharacters++;

            this.children.get(nextCharacter).addChild(numCharacters,value);
        }

    }


    public void reduce(){

                for(ConcurrentHashMap.Entry<String,TrieNode> child : this.children.entrySet()){

                    child.getValue().reduce();

                    //Get rid of original child mapping
                    this.children.remove(child.getKey());

                    //Replace with a new mapping which may include multiple characters if my child has been combined with other children
                    String newMapping = child.getValue().getValue().substring(this.getValue().length());

                    this.children.put(newMapping, child.getValue());

                }

                if(this.children.size() == 1){

                    for(ConcurrentHashMap.Entry<String,TrieNode> child : this.children.entrySet()){

                        //If I only have a single child, replace it with his children if I'm not also a word on my own
                        if(!this.isWord()){

                            //Get rid of the extra child node
                            this.children.remove(child.getKey());

                            //Take the child nodes value, word status and children
                            this.setValue(child.getValue().getValue());
                            this.setIsWord(child.getValue().isWord());

                            for(ConcurrentHashMap.Entry<String,TrieNode> grandchild : child.getValue().getChildrenMappings().entrySet()){
                                this.children.put(grandchild.getKey(),grandchild.getValue());
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }

    }

    public boolean isWord()
    {
        return this.isWord;
    }

    public void setIsWord(boolean isWord){
        this.isWord = isWord;
    }

    public String getValue()
    {
        return this.value;
    }

    public void setValue(String newValue){
        this.value = newValue;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){


        TrieNode tN = new TrieNode("");


        tN.addChild(0, "www.corriere.it/27esimaora/laquila");
        tN.addChild(0, "www.corriere.it/27esimaora");
        tN.addChild(0, "www.corriere.it/cronache/sesso-e-amore/");
        tN.addChild(0, "www.corriere.it/foto-gallery/cronache/sesso-e-amore/");

        tN.reduce();        

        ConcurrentHashMap<String, TrieNode> childrenMappings = tN.getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(0).getChildrenMappings();


        for(Map.Entry<String, TrieNode> children : childrenMappings.entrySet()){

            System.out.println(children.getKey() + " = " + children.getValue().getChildrenMappings() + children.getValue().getValue() + " "+ children.getValue().isWord);


        }

        System.out.println(tN.getChildren());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats too much code to look into buddy.Could you tell us what operation / calling which method is causing  infinite loop?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it @ArunGowda . That got resolved actually later. Yes, the needed implementation was quite complex.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code and added a condition that only if the new mapping not equal to the current child, then only remove the current child and add the new mapping.

I was also not sure what you were trying to print in the end. Therefore I have added my print statements.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

class TrieNode {

    private String value;
    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, TrieNode> children;
    private boolean isWord;

    public TrieNode(String value){
        this.value = value;
        this.children = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, TrieNode>();
    }

    public static void sortbykey(ConcurrentHashMap<String, TrieNode> map) {
        ArrayList<String> sortedKeys = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());

        Collections.sort(sortedKeys);

    }

    public static ArrayList<TrieNode> hashMapValues (ConcurrentHashMap<String, TrieNode> map) {
        ArrayList<TrieNode> nodeList = new ArrayList<TrieNode>(map.values());
        return nodeList;
    }

    public ArrayList<TrieNode> getChildren() {
        sortbykey(this.children);
        return hashMapValues(this.children);
    }

    public ConcurrentHashMap<String, TrieNode> getChildrenMappings()
    {
        return this.children;
    }

    public void addChild(int numCharacters,String value)
    {
        //If we have arrived at the root level
        if(value.length() == numCharacters)
        {
            this.isWord = true;
        }
        //If the value still has more characters then add a child
        else
        {
            TrieNode nextNode = null;
            String nextCharacter = Character.toString(value.charAt(numCharacters));
            if(this.children.get(nextCharacter)==null)
            {

                String nextPrefix = value.substring(0,numCharacters+1);
                nextNode = new TrieNode(nextPrefix);
                this.children.put(nextCharacter, nextNode);
            }
            numCharacters++;

            this.children.get(nextCharacter).addChild(numCharacters,value);
        }

    }


    public void reduce(){

        for(ConcurrentHashMap.Entry<String,TrieNode> child : this.children.entrySet()){

            child.getValue().reduce();


            //Get rid of original child mapping
            //this.children.remove(child.getKey());

            //Replace with a new mapping which may include multiple characters if my child has been combined with other children
            String newMapping = child.getValue().getValue().substring(this.getValue().length());

            // only if the new mapping is not equal.
            if (!newMapping.equals(child.getKey())) {
                this.children.remove(child.getKey());
                this.children.put(newMapping, child.getValue());
            }
            //this.children.put(newMapping, child.getValue());

        }

        if(this.children.size() == 1){

            for(ConcurrentHashMap.Entry<String,TrieNode> child : this.children.entrySet()){

                //If I only have a single child, replace it with his children if I'm not also a word on my own
                if(!this.isWord()){

                    //Get rid of the extra child node
                    this.children.remove(child.getKey());

                    //Take the child nodes value, word status and children
                    this.setValue(child.getValue().getValue());
                    this.setIsWord(child.getValue().isWord());
                    for(ConcurrentHashMap.Entry<String,TrieNode> grandchild : child.getValue().getChildrenMappings().entrySet()){
                        this.children.put(grandchild.getKey(),grandchild.getValue());
                    }

                }
            }

        }

    }

    public boolean isWord()
    {
        return this.isWord;
    }

    public void setIsWord(boolean isWord){
        this.isWord = isWord;
    }

    public String getValue()
    {
        return this.value;
    }

    public void setValue(String newValue){
        this.value = newValue;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){


        TrieNode tN = new TrieNode("");


        tN.addChild(0, "www.corriere.it/27esimaora/laquila");
        tN.addChild(0, "www.corriere.it/27esimaora");
        tN.addChild(0, "www.corriere.it/cronache/sesso-e-amore/");
        tN.addChild(0, "www.corriere.it/foto-gallery/cronache/sesso-e-amore/");

        tN.reduce();

        System.out.println(" root " + tN.getValue());
        System.out.println(" first level child 1 " + tN.getChildren().get(0).getValue());
        System.out.println(" first leve child 2 " + tN.getChildren().get(1).getValue());
        System.out.println(" second level child 1 " + tN.getChildren().get(1).getChildren().get(0).getValue());
        System.out.println(" first  level child 3 " + tN.getChildren().get(2).getValue());

        /*ConcurrentHashMap<String, TrieNode> childrenMappings = tN.getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(0).getChildrenMappings();


        for(Map.Entry<String, TrieNode> children : childrenMappings.entrySet()){

            System.out.println(children.getKey() + " = " + children.getValue().getChildrenMappings() + children.getValue().getValue() + " "+ children.getValue().isWord);


        }

        System.out.println(tN.getChildren());
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: @Amit please let us know if this solves the issue you are facing?

Comment: Hello @jainsuyogj, thanks a lot for your insights. The issue got resolved later, i created an altogether original mapping above. Yes the infinite loop was due to the updation of the same child mappings as that of the parent node. I was looping the same mappings to which i was updating to. So, creating original set of mapping lists and reducing them worked for me.

The approach seems similar to what you did, yes that will also resolve this issue as well. Very good catch, Really appreciate your help to look into this.